# Setting filename using for loop identifier

Tags: r, for-loop, save

I am trying to save the results of a for loop, where each loop selects a subset of a tibble and then fits this subset. I have 150 txt files, which I load into a dataframe using:

```
filelist = list.files(pattern = ".*.txt")

files <- stringr::str_sort(filelist, numeric = TRUE)

combined_files <- readr::read_delim(files, col_names = FALSE, id = "path")
names(combined_files) <- c("ID","f", "Re", "Im")
```

which give me the a data frame with the data from each file listed on after the other.

I then include a statement in the for loop which takes a subset of this data frame which corresponds to each file:

```
for (i in filter1$ID)
{

#Define total Z and calculate w
  
filter2 <- tibble(filter1$ID == i, filter1$f, filter1$Re, filter1$Im)
names(filter2) <- c("ID", "f", "Re", "Im")
```

The for loop appears to be working for the fitting aspect, however when I try to save the result at the end of the loop using:

```
write.csv(fit_dataframe, file = glue::glue("model_{i}.csv"))
```

I am not getting any output. Is there an easier way to do this? Happy to provide any more information.

Comment: Hi @Kieran, I am missing relevant parts of your code. What is the end of the loop? How do you define `fit_dataframe`?

Comment: Moreover I noticed that you are running the loop for each value of ID in `filter1$ID`, not each *unique* ID. Is this intended? This would mean that if you have n lines with the same ID, each model is fitted n times.

Comment: Hi @jkd . So the entire loop is quite long as it invovles a fitting procedure. I define fit_dataframe as : ``` fit_dataframe <- tibble(f, zr, zi, zr_cal, zi_cal) ```. The end of the loop is just making the dataframe with the initial data and the fitted result and then trying to save it. Do I need to include an iterative like command? The dataframe I am trying to iterate over has around 100 data points for each ID, and I am trying to get the loop to move through each ID (which I have just set to 1, 2, 3 etc) and apply the fitting, before outputting the result and then saving

Comment: @jkd - Not intended at all! I just realised this mistake and was about to update - how do I fix that it runs over each unique ID?

Comment: `for (i in unique(filter1$ID))`

Comment: Are the files you are loading initially one file per ID?

Comment: @jkd Hi, thanks! Yeah, each ID is one file, and I want to fit each  file to the model. I tried the i in unique(filter1$ID)) solution and it seems to still be iterating over each file more than once, as I am seeing 166 iterations and there are only 134 files. Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: If you see more iterations than you have files, you likely have more than one ID per file. Be aware that `unique` is case sensitive and will distinguish values with and without trailing whitespaces (just as an example of possible causes for more IDs than expected). To check the number of IDs use following command `length(unique(filter1$ID))`.

Answer (score 0):

It's still a bit unclear to me what you actually want to do.

If the issue is actually writing the results to a file, then your code should be functional.

MWE:

```r
library(tidyverse)

d <- data.frame(ID = rep(1:10, each=10),
                x = rnorm(100, 20, 4)) |>
  mutate(y = x*1.2+rnorm(100))

for (i in unique(d$ID)) {
  write.csv(d[d$ID==i,], file = glue::glue("model_{i}.csv"))
}
```

```r
> list.files(pattern="model")
 [1] "model_1.csv"  "model_10.csv" "model_2.csv"  "model_3.csv"  "model_4.csv"  "model_5.csv"  "model_6.csv"  "model_7.csv" 
 [9] "model_8.csv"  "model_9.csv"
```

So if you are sure that the files are not being produced, the error must be somewhere in between. Also note that `write.csv` will not produce console output if this is what you expected.

Regarding the general structure of your code I can only hypothesize but I would suggest following optimizations:

1. If the files you are reading and aggregating to a data frame in the first part of your code correspond to one file per ID, then I would suggest looping of the files directly (instead of 1. loop+aggregate, 2. loop of subset).

MWE:

```r
filelist <- list.files(pattern = ".*.txt")

for (i in filelist) {
  d <- readr::read_delim(i)
  fit <- lm(y ~ x, data = d)
}
```

2. If you want to compare the models between the IDs, then splitting the results into files is not ideal (however you can then ignore my first suggestion). An elegant solution would be to use `map` on a nested data frame.

MWE:

```r
library(tidyverse)

d <- data.frame(ID = rep(1:10, each=10),
                x = rnorm(100, 20, 4)) |>
  mutate(y = x*1.2+rnorm(100))

d |>
  nest(.by = ID) |>
  mutate(fit = map(data, ~ lm(y ~ x, data = .)),
         res = map(fit, broom::tidy)) |>
  unnest(res)
```

Comment: Hi, @jdk thanks again! Just a few questions (sorry). For looping to the files directly, how would I go about doing this? Take my list of file names and loop through loading them? I will take a look at the second method - I don't fully understand it currently but it looks very useful and much cleaner:) The only issue is my modelling is a bit complicated - I am first applying optim() and then using minpack.lm().

Comment: I have now added an example regarding the loop, however since `read.delim` is vectorized, the benefit of solution 1. may be limited. As I said, if you want to compare the different models in the end, solution 2. is likely the way to go.

Comment: Regarding the way solution 2 works, `nest` refactors your data frame into a data frame with one (or possibly more) grouping factor, and one `data` column containing the remaining columns as data.frame. This allows you to `map` a function to the data, in this case the modelling function. The result of the mapped function is returned inside a new column of data frame (via mutate), which allows you to keep everything together (ID, data, model).

Comment: Now regarding the modelling the first step would be refactor the modelling into a function you can call with your data as argument. If my present answer has helped, I would appreciate if you could accept it. To improve the modelling part, it would be easiest to recreate a minimal working example (e.g., on a single file) and ask a new question.