# Applying set of functions in a loop to each file in a folder

Tags: r, for-loop, text

I am trying to write a script which takes in a data file (here, a text file), fits a model to this file and then outputs the result. I have a script which works for inputting one file and outputs the required information, and I would like to now set up a for loop so that I can apply this script to every data file in a folder (I have 137 text files with names which only vary with a numeric identifier (First file is (filename)_1.txt etc). I am currently trying by creating a vector with each file name, and then using the loop to read each file:

```
filter2 <- read_delim(files2[[i]], col_names = FALSE)

names(filter2) <- c("f","Re", "Im")

for (i in 1:length(files2) {loop with fitting and plotting}
```

However, this seems to just be giving me a for loop which loops over the first file only. How would I make this iterate, one loop iteration runs the script on the first file, and then for the next iteration the second file is chosen? Happy to give more details - another aspect of my script was discussed in [Setting filename using for loop identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77511354/setting-filename-using-for-loop-identifier/77511545#77511545)

EDIT: I tried reading the file inside the loop but this also just seems to run on the loop on the first file:

```
names(filter2) <- c("f","Re", "Im")

for (i in 1:length(files2)) {

filter2[[i]] <- read_delim( file = filter3,  col_names = FALSE)
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358227 for some recommendations for this, though those discussions generally focus on "read in all data from multiple files". For your problem here, if you've already solved the "how to regress" problem, what's wrong with putting that code inside your `for` loop?

Comment: @r2evans Hi! Thanks for your response - I'll take a look. I'm not entirely sure - it just seems that the loop is only running on one file, and just continually optimising the fit to that file. It then gives an error as the change in fit becomes too small, which is why I think it is only reading on file. I will try putting everything inside though.

Comment: I don't understand. Your question reads as if you want each file to be regressed independently, but your comment here suggests to me that you need to either (a) run the model on all data combined; or (b) run the model on the first file, then the first 2 files, then the first 3 files, etc.

Comment: @r2evans The way the initial question reads is what I want to do - do the regression on one file, output the result, and then loop back and load the next file.

Comment: Okay, so why doesn't `for (file in allfiles) { dat <- read.delim(file,...); mdl <- lm(..., data=dat); dev.pdf(paste0(file, ".pdf")); some_plot(mdl); dev.off(); }` work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Giving a vector of names to `read_delim` only takes the last entry.

Using `sapply` to loop over the files found with `list.files` (`\\d+` -> one or more digits, `\\.` -> escaped dot).

```
library(readr)

sapply(list.files(pattern="filename_\\d+\\.txt"), \(x){
  data <- read_delim(x, col_names = FALSE)
  do-something(data)})
```

Using a `for` loop

```
library(readr)

for(i in list.files(pattern="filename_\\d+\\.txt")){
  data <- read_delim(i, col_names = FALSE)
  do-something(data)}
```